# ifstream doesn't read values from the file

Tags: c++, iostream, ifstream

I'm making a program that works with points and files. I have no warnings or errors, but it still doesn't work as it should. 
I think the problem is with the ifstream, cause the ofstream works well and puts entered the values into the file.

The output that i get looks like this

```
Please enter seven (x,y) pairs:
//here the seven pairs are entered

These are your points: 
//(...,...)x7 with the values

These are the points read from the file: 
//and the program ends and returns 0
```

I hope someone can help me.
Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

using namespace std;

struct Point{
    float x;
    float y;
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    return is >> p.x >> p.y;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Point& p)
{
    return os << '(' << p.x << ',' << p.y << ')';
}

void f() {
    vector<Point> original_points;
    cout << "Please enter seven (x,y) pairs: " << endl;
    for (Point p; original_points.size() < 7;) {
        cin >> p;
        original_points.push_back(p);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "These are your points: " << endl;
    for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
        cout << original_points[i] << endl;
    }
    string name = "mydata.txt";
    ofstream ost {name};
    if (!ost) error("can't open output file", name);
    for (Point p : original_points) {
        ost << '(' << p.x << ',' << p.y << ')' << endl;
    }
    ost.close();
    ifstream ist{name};
    if (!ist) error("can't open input file", name);
    vector<Point> processed_points;
    for (Point p; ist >> p;) {
        processed_points.push_back(p);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "These are the points read from the file: " << endl;
    for (int i=1; i <= processed_points.size(); i++) {
        cout << processed_points[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i=1; i <= processed_points.size(); i++) {`  Is this an off by 1 error? Remember array indices in c++ are 0 .. size-1, same goes for a std::vector

Comment: vector with the capital letter was a typo.

Comment: when i change i=1 to i=0 i get a range error

Comment: `for (int i=1; i <= processed_points.size(); i++) {` should be `for (int i=0; i < processed_points.size(); i++) {` or just use a range based for loop. See the examples at the bottom of this: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!! It works now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output brackets and a comma but you don't consume them so your first read operation will fail. Try:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Point& p)
{
    char open;
    char close;
    char comma;
    is >> open >> p.x >> comma >> p.y >> close;
    if (open != '(' || close != ')' || comma != ',')
    {
      is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
    }
    return is;
}
```

Your program will also crash at the end due to going out of the bounds of the vector, you are using indexes from `1` to `length`, vectors are 0-indexed so should be accessed from `0` to `length-1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < processed_points.size(); i++) {
    cout << processed_points[i] << endl;
}
```

Or just use a range based loop:

```
for (auto& point : processed_points) {
    cout << point  << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you! i needed this for the input, but i still have the problem with outputting the points from file. I still get an empty vector

Comment: You get an empty vector because your input is failing.

Comment: @marta fixing your second bug makes your code work for me

Comment: @AlanBirtles now it works too!! thank you so much for help